# How to run EXE file from bundle as Administrator - WIx

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wix

I have bundled all my two .msi using Wix bootstraper application into single `EXE` file.

One msi is with `per user context` which uninstall a application with `per user context` and install own.

second one is with `per machine context` and this also installs the files in windows drive.I have bundled both MSI as `single EXE`.

Now if i open the EXE as `Run as Administrator`,the EXE is uninstalling the `per user package` and installation happens successfully. If i directly double click the `EXE package`, during the removal of `per user package` i am getting the following exception "`Error 1001.An exception occured during uninstalling....->Requested registry access is not allowed`". and installation failed.

I tried adding a `manifest` file in BA to include in to `EXE package` to prompt the `administrator privilege` during double click. After doing this and building in VS2010, all other two package are not included in EXE file and if i double click the EXE it is showing the UAC and close without installing.

Is it possible to catch the installer exception from WIX and show a message like "`Please right click and run as administrator`" to user.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: The WiX Burn engine creates a log in the user's temp directory, can you post that?  Your description of the problem doesn't give enough information (it shouldn't matter whether you "Run as Administrator" or not).

Comment: @SeanHall Can you tell me in Which directory the log file will be available.

Comment: %TEMP%.  C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Temp for Vista/Win7/Win8

Comment: @SeanHall I have updated the question with actual problem i am facing.Please update me what i can do to solve this.